# Is the fastest open determined by preceeding key slots?

Tags: luks, decryption

After installing LUKS (v1) devices with openSUSE LEap 15.2, it turned out that the iteration count was set so high that it takes more than 10 seconds for a successful decryption of the master key (bug reports exist on that).

So I added a second key slot using a much smaller iteration count.

However I wonder:
AFAIK after entering a pass phrase, luksOpen will try to decrypt the key slots in sequence, not in parallel, meaning that the first key slot determines the minimum waiting time until decryption succeeds.
Is that correct?

Note: When booting, I cannot specify parameters to select a specific key slot.
So the most likely solution would be swapping key slots, right?

Answer (score 2):

## Test setup

1. Create a file in ramdisk to hold the LUKS container:

   ```
   $ cd /dev/shm
   $ truncate -s 1G luksfile
   ```
2. Prepare identical size keyfiles for testing:

   ```
   $ dd if=/dev/urandom of=key1 bs=1M count=1
   1+0 records in
   1+0 records out
   1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 0,00897814 s, 117 MB/s
   $ dd if=/dev/urandom of=key2 bs=1M count=1
   1+0 records in
   1+0 records out
   1048576 bytes (1,0 MB, 1,0 MiB) copied, 0,00792946 s, 132 MB/s
   ```
3. Format the file:

   ```
   $ cryptsetup luksFormat --key-file key1 luksfile

   WARNING!
   ========
   This will overwrite data on luksfile irrevocably.

   Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
   ```
4. Add the 2nd key:

   ```
   $ cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-file key1 luksfile key2
   ```

## The test

```
for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do  
time sudo cryptsetup open --key-file key1 luksfile test
sudo cryptsetup close test
done
```

I'm discarding results from the first 5 runs for each key to eliminate caching discrepancies.

Results for `key1`:

```
2,30s user 0,02s system 97% cpu 2,369 total
2,39s user 0,01s system 97% cpu 2,454 total
2,41s user 0,02s system 97% cpu 2,509 total
2,25s user 0,02s system 97% cpu 2,336 total
2,21s user 0,02s system 97% cpu 2,291 total
```

Results for `key2`:

```
4,08s user 0,02s system 98% cpu 4,146 total
4,20s user 0,02s system 98% cpu 4,267 total
4,19s user 0,01s system 98% cpu 4,255 total
4,15s user 0,01s system 98% cpu 4,209 total
4,43s user 0,02s system 98% cpu 4,520 total
```

**Yes, keys are checked one by one.** 2nd key will be affected by 1st key's slowness.

## Solution

> When booting, I cannot specify parameters to select a specific key slot.

Actually you can. Use the `keyslot` option in `/etc/crypttab`, 4th column. See `man crypttab`.

Comment: A final question on "Use the keyslot option in /etc/crypttab": Is there a fall-back? That is: If I specify key slot 1 and at some later time I clear that slot, will I still be able to boot then?

Comment: @U.Windl You really underestimate the usefulness of manual ;) `man crypttab` will refer you to `cryptsetup -S` and `man cryptsetup` says _"If the given passphrase would only match a different key-slot, the operation fails."_

Comment: So using that option is dangerous, and that slot is not the *preferred* one, but the *required* one. That ("If the given passphrase would only match a different key-slot, the operation fails.") could be considered to be a bug even.

Comment: Maybe also see https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/issues/643

Comment: @U.Windl Well, performing administrative tasks like this one is inherently dangerous. So just double check everything, have a recovery plan and make sure your backups work.